# VBA Data pasting in wrong cells sometimes

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to write a macro that:
Iterates over a list of employee IDs, identifies whether it needs a report generated or not then, filters a large dataset to include only that employee, grab several different columns, and paste them into a formatted sheet. It will then copy that sheet and save it into a file directory as a binary file.

The code works as expected sometimes, but other times, it seems to be pasting the all the data in a different row (it varies, but is usually between rows 8800 and 9200). I want it to paste in Row 2. The only clue that I have found to indicate the cause is that column S, where Gross Margin is stored, seems to have a couple hundred rows of data above where the table starts (only in some cases though). All data is still lining up in the correct rows.

```
Sub SplitFile()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Set pivots = wb.Sheets("Pivots")
Set repository = wb.Sheets("Repository")
Set listing = wb.Sheets("Customer Listing")
For Each rep In pivots.Range("A4:A" & pivots.Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row)
    If rep.Offset(0, 1) <> "" Then
        Debug.Print rep
        lastRow = repository.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
        repName = rep.Offset(0, 1).Value
        repDistrict = rep.Offset(0, 2).Value
        folderPath = pivots.Range("B1").Value & "\" & repDistrict
        
        repository.Range("A1:AU" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=33, Criteria1:=rep
        
        'EEID and Name
        repository.Range("AG2:AH" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy listing.Range("A2")
        
        'Source
        repository.Range("F2:F" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy listing.Range("C2")
        'Cust ID
        repository.Range("H2:H" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy listing.Range("D2")
        'Cust Name
        repository.Range("K2:K" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy listing.Range("E2")
        'Address Details
        repository.Range("S2:U" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy listing.Range("F2")
        'Predominant Trade, Active/Inactive, Start Date
        repository.Range("W2:Y" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy listing.Range("I2")

        'Region & District
        repository.Range("AA2:AB" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy listing.Range("L2")
        
        'Pay Terms
        repository.Range("AQ2:AQ" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy listing.Range("N2")
        
        'Revenue and Margin
        repository.Range("L2:M" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy listing.Range("O2")
        repository.Range("N2:N" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy listing.Range("R2")
        repository.Range("O2:O" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy listing.Range("S2") 'my guess is this is about where the problem is. 
        
        'Sort Data
        listing.Columns("A:W").Sort key1:=listing.Range("P1"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
        
        'Formulas
        lastListingRow = listing.Cells(1000000, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        listing.Range("Q2:Q" & lastListingRow).Formula = "=IFERROR(P2/O2,"""")"
        listing.Range("T2:T" & lastListingRow).Formula = "=IFERROR(S2/R2,"""")"
        listing.Range("U2:V" & lastListingRow).Formula = "=IFERROR(O2-R2,"""")"
        listing.Range("W2:W" & lastListingRow).Formula = "=IFERROR(ROUND((Q2-T2)*10000,0),"""")"
        
        'Paste formulas
        'lastListingRow = listing.Cells(1000000, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        'listing.Range("Q2").Copy listing.Range("Q3:Q" & listingLastRow)
        'listing.Range("Q2").Copy listing.Range("T3:T" & listingLastRow)
        'listing.Range("U2").Copy listing.Range("U3:V" & listingLastRow)
        'listing.Range("W2").Copy listing.Range("W3:W" & listingLastRow)
        
        
        
        If Dir(folderPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
            MkDir (folderPath)
        End If
        listing.Copy
        Set newWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
        newWb.SaveAs folderPath & "\" & repDistrict & "-" & rep & "-" & repName & "-" & pivots.Range("H1"), FileFormat:=50
        newWb.Close
        listing.Range("A2:R9000").Value = ""
        repository.ShowAllData
        
    End If
Next
```

End Sub

I am not using option explicit as I tend to code mostly in python and have grown used to "duck typing".

I'd appreciate any help, and can clarify if you need it. I've never run into this problem before, but I've written several programs like it.

Comment: In each case you're pasting to a fixed range, so there's nothing I can see in your code which would explain the problem you're seeing, unless the visible rows contain a lot of blank cells.

Comment: @TimWilliams That's what I would think too. And I've checked the data several times and there are no blank rows in the set. Especially when it is filtered to an individual.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this occurred, but I fixed it by replacing `listing.Range("A2:R9000").Value = ""` with `listing.Rows("2:100000").delete`.

Comment: You may have has some non-visible and non-printable characters in there somewhere.